# ActiveX WScript.Shell: Opening multiple PDFs with a loop

Tags: javascript, cmd, activex

I'm trying to open multiple PDFs using a command from Javascript, but with each iteration, I have to close the most recently opened PDF before the next file will open. I've been reading through the documentation trying to figure out what I need to fix, but I'm not sure where to start.

```
var Shell = ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"),
    folder = "A:\Folder\On\My\Computer";

Shell.Run('cmd /c for %f in ("' + folder + '\\*.pdf") do (%~f)');
```

Comment: What program is actually displaying the PDFs?

Comment: It's Adobe Acrobat 2017.